# ASP.NET Set variable if Request.QueryString does not exist

Tags: c#, if-statement, query-string

I want to set a textbox.text to a certain value if Request.QueryString['EQCN'] does not exist. If it does exist, I would like to set it to the value of Requestion.QueryString['EQCN'].

It seems that if the value doesn't exist it defaults the value to be "".

Any ideas?

Thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the parameter is not in the query string, the QueryString indexer will return a `null` reference, so you can use the `??` operator for a default value:

```
textbox.text = Request.QueryString['EQCN'] ?? "default text";
```

Answer (score 3):

```
textbox.text = string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["EQCN"]) ? "my value" : Request.QueryString["EQCN"];
```